# How can I execute this AJAX/JSONP code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Someone answered in my past question and provided me with the code necessary to pull a datetime from a server. All is well it's just that I don't know how to execute it! for example, I want to the action to happen on pageload, how can I do that?

here's the Ajax/JSONP code I was given:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
.done(function(response) {
    // response = {"dateString":"2012-03-06T02:18:25+00:00"}
    console.log(response.dateString);// "2012-03-06T02:18:25+00:00"
});
```

P.S. does the "$" refer to JQuery? I am not very familiar with this syntax...the $.ajax and the .done?

Comment: Yes. You need to learn jQuery.

Comment: I'd use `$.getJSON` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ - but i'm pretty sure the type should be just `'json'` p.s. yes, $ refer to the jQuery "object"

Comment: double check API docs that they deliver jsonp and that you don't need to provide any special callback name for jsonp wrapper. Many people assume that an API that delivers json also delivers jsonp, not true

Comment: I mean I am mostly concerned about actually running this in my code. Do I like include this inside a function that I call onload?

Comment: You have to include the jQuery library in your page and then wrap this script in a document ready wrapper, $(document).ready(function() { // your ajax code here }); Start here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jyXHA/ (but without know the basics of jQuery, that's more of a crutch than anything)

Comment: @isotrope, thanks! this works great for me. is there any way to return the value? or at least set a global variable to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely have to check out [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

Basically, `$` refers to the jQuery object, and `.ajax()` and `.done()` are functions which are properties of this object. They can be concatenated by a common technique of returning the jquery-context at the end of each function.

Simplified you have something like this:

`jQuery.function(parameters).anotherfunction(parameters)`

You should start with this [basic tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#jQuery%3a_The_Basics).